# Training Job in Sagemaker gives error in locating file in S3 to docker image path

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use `scikit_bring_your_own/container/decision_trees/train mode`, running in AWS CLI, I had no issues. Trying to replicate in Creating Sagemaker Training Job , facing issue in loading data from S3 to docker image path.

In CLI command we used specify the `docker run -v $(pwd)/test_dir:/opt/ml --rm ${image} train` from where the input needs to referred.

In training job, mentioned the S3 bucket location and output path for model artifacts.

```
Error entered in the exception as in train - "container/decision_trees/train"
raise ValueError(('There are no files in {}.\n' + 
'This usually indicates that the channel ({}) was incorrectly specified,\n'  + 
'the data specification in S3 was incorrectly specified or the role specified\n' +
'does not have permission to access the data.').format(training_path, channel_name))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/program/train", line 55, in train
'does not have permission to access the data.').format(training_path, channel_name))
```

So not understanding is there any tweaking required or any access missing.

kindly help

Answer (score 2):

If you set the InputDataConfig in the CreateTrainingJob API like this

```
"InputDataConfig": [ 
  { 
     "ChannelName": "train",
     "DataSource": { 
        "S3DataSource": { 
           "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
           "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
           "S3Uri": "s3://<bucket>/a.csv"
        }
     },
     "InputMode": "File",
  },
  { 
     "ChannelName": "eval",
     "DataSource": { 
        "S3DataSource": { 
           "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
           "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
           "S3Uri": "s3://<bucket>/b.csv"
        }
     },
     "InputMode": "File",
  }
]
```

SageMaker download the data specified above from S3 to the /opt/ml/input/data/channel_name directory in the Docker container. In this case, the algorithm container should be able to find the input data under

```
/opt/ml/input/data/train/a.csv
/opt/ml/input/data/eval/b.csv
```

You can find more details in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo.html